# Caching objects inbetween tests using pytest-django

Tags: django, pytest-django

I am trying to speed up my unit tests by caching objects inbetween tests.

I know that tests ought to be isolated from one another.  But the act of creating my objects is expensive and there is no need to keep creating the same objects over-and-over again.

Originally, I thought I could call a fixture from `setup_class` but apparently that doesn't work.  So I have just written a simple function to call at the start of each test.  This *nearly* works.  However, the related objects are empty.

Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

**tests.py:**

```
import factory
import pytest
from faker import Faker
from django.db import models

from models import Book, Author

fake = Faker()

class AuthorFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
    name = factory.Faker('name')

class BookFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
    title = factory.Faker('sentence')
    author = factory.SubFactory(AuthorFactory)

def make_an_author(**kwargs):

    n_books = kwargs.pop("n_books", 10)

    author = AuthorFactory.create(**kwargs)
    for i in range(n_books):
        BookFactory.create(author=author)

    return author

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestAuthor:

    N_AUTHORS = 10
    cached_authors = []

    def cache_authors(self, n_authors):
        current_n_authors = len(self.cached_authors)
        if current_n_authors < n_authors:
            self.cached_authors.extend(
                [
                    make_an_author(n_books=2)
                    for i in range(current_n_authors, n_authors)
                ]
            )

    def test_one(self, cache_authors):
        self.cache_authors(10)
        author = fake.choice(self.cached_authors)
        # THIS WORKS!
        assert author.books.count() != 0

    def test_two(self, cache_authors):
        self.cache_authors(10)
        author = fake.choice(self.cached_authors)
        # THIS FAILS!
        assert author.books.count() != 0
```

Everytime after the first test, the reverse relationship between Author & Books is empty.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option here is perhaps to prefetch the `Book` objects when you cache the `Author`. Currently the `Book`s are looked up on demand via the `RelatedManager` on the `Author`. That lookup doesn't work on the second test, because the transaction was torn down after the first test in which the objects were originally cached.

You can try:

```
def make_an_author(**kwargs):

    n_books = kwargs.pop("n_books", 10)

    author = AuthorFactory.create(**kwargs)
    for i in range(n_books):
        BookFactory.create(author=author)

    # Prefetch the books before caching the author
    author = Author.objects.prefetch_related('books').get(pk=author.pk)

    return author
```